# Where can I find the source code for the R function sequence()

Tags: r

I would like to read the source code for the `base::sequence()` function.

In R Studio, I can press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and usually read the code, though this time the cryptic response is:

```
function (nvec, ...) 
UseMethod("sequence")
```

I search the Read-only mirror of R source code at:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?q=sequence

And could not find the code there.

Comment: Look at `sequence.default`.

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0a05488b8d2455983ac290a1804af0bf427d6475/src/main/seq.c#L1115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
sequence.default
function (nvec, from = 1L, by = 1L, ...) 
{
    .Internal(sequence(as.integer(nvec), as.integer(from), as.integer(by)))
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff50ed324b0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Then, the `sequence` function is internal and you can find the source code here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0a05488b8d2455983ac290a1804af0bf427d6475/src/main/seq.c#L1115